# org.apache.kafka.common.config.ConfigException : StringDeserializer could not be found

Tags: java, apache-kafka

I am trying to replay some offset, here is the kafka consumer that I have.  The same code is working fine in my local environment, but when i deploy in our DEV environment it is failing with below error. I am using `<kafka.client.version>3.4.0</kafka.client.version>`

```
Properties consumerProperties = new Properties();
consumerProperties.put(ConsumerConfig.BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS_CONFIG, kafkaProperties.getBootstrapServers());
consumerProperties.put(ConsumerConfig.KEY_DESERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, StringDeserializer.class.getName());
consumerProperties.put(ConsumerConfig.VALUE_DESERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, StringDeserializer.class.getName());


KafkaConsumer<String, String> consumer = new KafkaConsumer<>(props);
```

Error Stack:

```
 stack_trace: org.apache.kafka.common.config.ConfigException: Invalid value org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringDeserializer for configuration key.deserializer: Class org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringDeserializer could not be found.
at org.apache.kafka.common.config.ConfigDef.parseType(ConfigDef.java:744)
at org.apache.kafka.common.config.ConfigDef.parseValue(ConfigDef.java:490)
at org.apache.kafka.common.config.ConfigDef.parse(ConfigDef.java:483)
at org.apache.kafka.common.config.AbstractConfig.<init>(AbstractConfig.java:113)
at org.apache.kafka.common.config.AbstractConfig.<init>(AbstractConfig.java:133)
at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.ConsumerConfig.<init>(ConsumerConfig.java:652)
at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.KafkaConsumer.<init>(KafkaConsumer.java:665)
at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.KafkaConsumer.<init>(KafkaConsumer.java:646)
at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.KafkaConsumer.<init>(KafkaConsumer.java:626)
at java.base/java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture$AsyncRun.run(CompletableFuture.java:1804)
at util.TokenAwareRunnable.run(TokenAwareRunnable.java:28)
at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinTask$RunnableExecuteAction.exec(ForkJoinTask.java:1395)
at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinTask.doExec(ForkJoinTask.java:373)
at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinPool$WorkQueue.topLevelExec(ForkJoinPool.java:1182)
at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinPool.scan(ForkJoinPool.java:1655)
at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinPool.runWorker(ForkJoinPool.java:1622)
at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinWorkerThread.run(ForkJoinWorkerThread.java:165)
```

any help here ?  seems like classloader is not finding the StringDeserializer class.  May be build issue?

Comment: `<kafka.client.version>3.4.0</kafka.client.version>` is just a property, not a dependency. Show your full pom, please